# How to get On-Behalf-Of-User token in .NET using ADAL

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-graph-api

I have created an Azure AAD app of type webapp which has client secret and redirect url. Now, I want to get an access token on behalf of user using the AAD app. From looking at the documentation, I got the following code so far.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var clientId = "<REDACTED>";
        var clientSecret = "<REDACTED>";
        var resourceAppIdURI = "https://api.office.com/discovery/";
        var authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";

        AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext(authority, new FileCache());
        ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

        // Get token as application
        var task = ac.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceAppIdURI, cc);
        task.Wait();
        var appToken = task.Result.AccessToken;

        // Get tokenn on behalf of user
        UserCredential uc = new UserCredential("usrname@mytenant.com");
        task = ac.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceAppIdURI, clientId, uc);
        var userToken = task.Result.AccessToken;

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

But this is the error I get when I try to get user token is as follows.

> Message   "AADSTS70002: The request body must contain the following
>   parameter: 'client_secret or client_assertion'.\r\nTrace ID:
>   0e977f67-d5cb-4cf5-8fea-bac04b6d0400\r\nCorrelation ID:
>   824a96bf-8007-4879-970c-2680644b8669\r\nTimestamp: 2017-07-21
>   05:02:41Z"    string

Why am I getting this error and how to fix it?
Do I need to login with the user first and then use UserAssertion instead ?
There are tonnes of overloaded methods for AcquireTokenAsync method, but not sure what I should use.

I also looked at this github url to see how they are doing it
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof/blob/8afb3e6a648d8e7246685bf6747d009006c761b8/TodoListService/Controllers/TodoListController.cs

This is the relevant code to get token as logged in user

```
    ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
    var bootstrapContext = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First().BootstrapContext as System.IdentityModel.Tokens.BootstrapContext;
    string userName = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Upn) != null ? ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Upn).Value : ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value;
    string userAccessToken = bootstrapContext.Token;
    UserAssertion userAssertion = new UserAssertion(bootstrapContext.Token, "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer", userName);

    string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);
    string userId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
    AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, new DbTokenCache(userId));
```

Here they already have a logged in user and creating a UserAssertion from that loggedin user's token. In my console app, the user hasn't logged in yet.
So I need a way to do this in my console app. How can I show the AAD login page to the user as a pop-up and then once the user enters creds use that info to create an UserAssertion object?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scenario is a native application that calls a web API on behalf of a user . The native application could obtains an access token for the user by using the [OAuth 2.0 authorization code grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code) , then access token is then sent in the request to the web API, which authorizes the user and returns the desired resource :
[image]

Please read more about the description of protocol flow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#native-application-to-web-api) .Also see the [code samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-code-samples#native-application-to-web-api) for Native Application to Web API scenarios.

In addition , you could click [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console) for code sample about how to call the Azure AD Graph API from a native client(.net console application ) ,it uses the Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) for authentication .

Comment: I really don't want to use another aad app (native client) for getting on behalf of user token. When I try to get access token using postman app, and supply the webapp aad app credentials it does get the on behalf of user token. So how can I do that same thing in my console app?

Comment: If your requirement is in console app , show the AAD login page to the user as a pop-up , and get the access token on behalf of user , then you should register a native app in AAD. What is your scenario ?

Comment: I see. If I use powershell instead of console app, can I use the same webapp credentials to login with user showing a pop-up or does it also still need a native app. My scenario is I only have one webapp created and don't have access to aad to create more apps and I want to test some apis that require using on behalf of user access token. It console app is not the right approach then let me know what else I can use to test the api responses given I only have one webapp

Comment: Native app would not be able to protect a secret, you could try web app  that uses Azure AD for sign-in using the OpenID Connect protocol ,using adal to acquire token and try the apis you want with access token , please refer to [this code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect .) . And if you want to try microsoft graph apis or azure ad graph apis , you could try [Microsoft Graph explorer ](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and [Azure AD Graph Explorer](https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net/)